# Syntax Error in SQL UPDATE statement but it all seems ok :(

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I am getting this error with one of my tables in a database:

(An exception of type `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException` occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.)

It allows me to read from it but when I come to add a new record or update it using an SQL query it gives me this error, I have checked, double checked and triple checked but can't see anything wrong with it...strange thing is is I took it from another table which I know was working and made sure I changed all the variables but to no avail!

Apologies if you all think this is very dirty code, its my first year project and I'm still getting my head round quicker ways to do things!

If anyone could have a look at it and see if they can figure it out, it would be much appreciated!

```
Sub Update()

    Dim cs As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("mydatabasename") + ";"
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(cs)
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim r As OleDbDataReader
    Dim ite As String
    Dim siz As String
    Dim quantit As String
    Dim pric As String
    Dim sourc As String
    Dim updatestockstrings As String
    updatestockstrings = Request.QueryString("updatestock")
    ite = itm.Value
    siz = sze.Value
    quantit = qty.Value
    pric = prc.Value
    sourc = imgsrc.Value
    If ite = "" Then
        parMsg.InnerHtml = "Please add an item name"
    ElseIf siz = "" Then
        parMsg.InnerHtml = "Please add a size"
    ElseIf quantit = "" Then
        parMsg.InnerHtml = "Please add a quantity"
    ElseIf pric = "" Then
        parMsg.InnerHtml = "Please state a price"
    ElseIf sourc = "" Then
        parMsg.InnerHtml = "Please add an image source"
    Else
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stocks Set Item='" & ite & "', Size='" & siz & "', Quantity='" & quantit & "', Price='" & pric & "', ImageSource='" & sourc & "' WHERE StockID=" & updatestockstrings & ";", cn)
        cn.Open()
        r = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        Do While r.Read()
        Loop
        cn.Close()
        parMsg.InnerHtml = "Update Successful!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe an out of context question by why do each of the variables above lack the last letter?

Comment: First, **stop concatenating SQL statements**. Search for SQL injection, and then search here at SO for "vb.net parameterized queries". To solve your current problem, store the SQL in a string (instead of putting it directly in the OleDBCommand) and add a messagebox that shows you the completed SQL statement.

Comment: If would be helpful if you posted the actual SQL statement generated instead of the code that builds it. Or better yet, open that SQL Statement in SSMS and try to run it and you will see exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIZE is a reserved word in MS-Access, you need to put square brackets around it

```
[SIZE]=......
```

But I really suggest to use a parameterized query to defend yourself from SQL Injection and parsing problems (What happens if one or more of your input strings contains a single quote?)

```
 cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Stocks Set Item=?, [Size]=?, Quantity=?, " & _
           "Price=?, ImageSource=? WHERE StockID=?", cn)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", item)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", siz)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", quantit )
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", pric)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", sourc)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", updatestockstrings)
```

But this is still not enough. You should pass parameters with the correct datatype for the underlying database field. So, for example, if the database field `Price` is a decimal column then you need to convert the `pric` variable to a decimal value (and this requires that you parse it to be sure that you have received a valid decimal value)

Comment: Do you have to create a parameters file as when I use this I get "BC30451: 'Parameters' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." I use the get help and it says generate parameters class and it creates parameters.vb which is a blank file but still gives me the same error?

Comment: That's strange. Probably some kind of typo error because Parameters is definitively a property of an OleDbCommand http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In extension to [*@Steve's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23023505/767881), on your posting,

You have to use [*`ExecuteNonQuery`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#exampleToggle) on statements like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE`. It returns the number of records affected but not a `ResultSet` to read records from.

[*`ExecuteReader`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for `SELECT` statements that returns a set of records to read.

**Change**:

```
cn.Open()
r = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Do While r.Read()
Loop
cn.Close()
```

**To**:

```
cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Unless required, capturing the result of `ExecuteNonQuery` into an integer is optional.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, it was the Size that was causing the problem.  If I understand you correctly, I cannot use 'ExecureReader' for an UPDATE/INSERT etc only a SELECT statement however, it works... I have not changed that and the statement still updates.  I don't really userstand how to use the parametarized query, are the '@'p1, '@'p2 etc the text boxes that are being used to input the data? Thanks

Comment: @Figrol: Read about [*SqlCommand.Parameters*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), for more details.

Comment: Yes, ExecuteReader works but this doesn't mean that you should use it. ExecuteReader, after executing whatever the commandtext is, builds an internal infrastructure to read data back from the open connection. Instead ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery doesn't need to build that infrastructure